# Cast pointer to fixed-size array in return statement

Tags: c++, arrays

The simplest way to ask this question is with some code:

```
struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;

    int* as_pointer() { return &x; }        // works
    int (&as_array_ref())[3] { return &x; } // does not work   
};
```

`as_pointer` compiles, `as_array_ref` does not. A cast seems to be in order but I can't figure out the appropriate syntax. Any ideas?

Comment: So you want the compiler to pretend that `x` is, in fact, an array of three `int`s? There's no guarantee that this will work; compilers can add padding between data members in ways that are different from the way that they lay out arrays.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I find that array types are easier to deal with with a typedef:

```
typedef int ints[3];
```

Then your `as_array_ref` must be written so that `&as_array_ref() == &x`.

The following syntaxes are possible:

1. plain C-style cast from `int*` to `ints*`:

   `ints& as_array_ref() { return *( (ints*)(&x) ); }`
2. C++ style `reinterpret_cast` (suggested by @Mike Seymour - see also his answer). It is often  considered a better practice in C++:

   `ints& as_array_ref() { return *reinterpret_cast<ints*>(&x); }`
3. Cast from `int&` to `ints&` which is slightly shorter but (for me) less intuitive:

   `ints& as_array_ref() { return reinterpret_cast<ints&>(x); }`

Comment: I'd rather see a C++ style `reinterpret_cast` to make it more obvious that something dodgy is happening. C-style casts are both dangerous and difficult to search for.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: indeed it's more C++ like. I edited my answer accordingly, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

The cast you need to reinterpret a reference to a variable as a reference to an array is:

```
reinterpret_cast<int(&)[3]>(x);
```

Be aware that using this gives undefined behaviour; it will probably work on any sensible implementation, but there's no guarantee that there won't be padding between the members of the class, while arrays are not padded.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you're trying to do would be easier (and clearer/cleaner) with an union.

Comment: Also a very good suggestion, thanks. I normally avoid them so the thought didn't even cross my mind!

Comment: I'm not sure about cleaner: in both cases if struct-fields and arrays happen to have different padding/alignment it won't work. So unless I'm mistaken both solutions are dangerous.