# "Incompatible types" when using C and C++ to interact with C String in FreeRTOS queue

Tags: c++, c, pointers, esp32

I'm working on the following CPP function to write an array of bytes with given length into a FreeRTOS queue struct. A C function will then consume the data from the queue.

The intent here is to reference txData's address in the cmdBuf.

```
/*In header:
typedef struct {
    uint16_t spp_conn_id;
    esp_gatt_if_t spp_gatts_if;
    uint16_t command;
    size_t length;
    uint8_t payload[PAYLOAD_SIZE];
    TaskHandle_t taskHandle;
} CMD_t;
*/
void BLESerialTx(const uint8_t *txData, size_t txLen)
{
    CMD_t cmdBuf;
    cmdBuf.command = CMD_UART_DATA;
    if (txLen) {
        cmdBuf.length = txLen;
        cmdBuf.payload = txData;
        xQueueSend(xQueueToBLE, &cmdBuf, portMAX_DELAY);
    }
}
```

However, I get the compiler error "incompatible types in assignment of 'const uint8_t*' {aka 'const unsigned char*'} to 'uint8_t [128]' {aka 'unsigned char [128]'}"

Looking around at similar questions on Stack Overflow, it seems that the uint8_t* has to remain const to avoid undefined behavior in cpp. However, even if I try to be more explicit with the following

```
cmdBuf.payload = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t>(const_cast<uint8_t>(txData));
```

I still get the error  "incompatible types in assignment of 'uint8_t' {aka 'unsigned char'} to 'uint8_t [128]' {aka 'unsigned char [128]'}"

..Shouldn't char * and char[128] be relatively the same? I don't understand what the proper way to do this would be.

This is for ESP32 using espidf v5.0.1

Comment: Arrays are not pointers, and pointers are not arrays. You can't assign to arrays; you need to copy the payload using other means, such as `std::copy`.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212843/cast-pointer-to-fixed-size-array-in-return-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212843/cast-pointer-to-fixed-size-array-in-return-statement)

Comment: Thanks, @molbdnilo! Coming from C I'm used to them being synonymous

Comment: @Drewster They're not synonymous in C, either.

Comment: For anyone reading through this later, my issue was not seeing my code initializing an array with a pointer. I intended to pass a pointer, but because the struct defines payload as payload[PAYLOAD_SIZE]
it means my code was more or less trying to say 
payload[PAYLOAD_SIZE] = uint8_t *txData;
Seeing it this way makes the mistake more obvious, and is explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914220/c-error-incompatible-types-in-assignment-of-char-to-char-2